# restricting the addresses riak2 listens to (kernel, {inet_dist_use_interface, inet:ip_address()})

Tags: riak

All our erlang nodes listen on their private address only. With riak 1, we used to add something akin to the following to `app.config`:

```
{kernel, [        
          {inet_dist_use_interface, {192,168,0,42}},
```

That no longer seems possible with riak 2. `riak.conf` does not allow for arbitrary application parameters. So I gave `vm.args` a shot:

```
-kernel inet_dist_use_interface '{192,168,0,42}'
```

That, in turn, caused the following error:

```
{application_start_failure,                                                  
   riak_core,                                                                  
   {bad_return,                                                                
    {{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},                                        
     {'EXIT',                                                                  
      {{function_clause,                                                       
        [{orddict,                                                             
          fetch,                                                               
          [nonode@nohost,                                                      
           [{'riak@192.168.0.42',                                              
             [{{riak_control,member_info_version},[v1,v0]},                    
              {{riak_core,bucket_types},[true,false]},                         
              {{riak_core,fold_req_version},[v2,v1]},                          
              {{riak_core,net_ticktime},[true,false]},                         
              {{riak_core,resizable_ring},[true,false]},                       
              {{riak_core,security},[true,false]},                             
              {{riak_core,staged_joins},[true,false]},                         
              {{riak_core,vnode_routing},[proxy,legacy]},                      
              {{riak_kv,anti_entropy},[enabled_v1,disabled]},                  
              {{riak_kv,crdt},                                                 
               [[pncounter,riak_dt_pncounter,riak_dt_orswot,riak_dt_map],      
                [pncounter],                                                   
                []]},                                                          
              {{riak_kv,crdt_epoch_versions},                                  
               [[{riak_dt_map,2},{riak_dt_orswot,2},{riak_dt_pncounter,2}],    
                [{riak_dt_pncounter,2}]]},                                     
              {{riak_kv,handoff_data_encoding},[encode_raw,encode_zlib]},      
              {{riak_kv,index_backpressure},[true,false]},                     
              {{riak_kv,legacy_keylisting},[false]},                           
              {{riak_kv,listkeys_backpressure},[true,false]},                  
              {{riak_kv,mapred_2i_pipe},[true,false]},                         
              {{riak_kv,mapred_system},[pipe]},                                
              {{riak_kv,object_format},[v1,v0]},                               
              {{riak_kv,put_fsm_ack_execute},[enabled,disabled]},              
              {{riak_kv,secondary_index_version},[v3,v2,v1]},                  
              {{riak_kv,vclock_data_encoding},[encode_zlib,encode_raw]},       
              {{riak_kv,vnode_vclocks},[true,false]},                          
              {{riak_pipe,trace_format},[ordsets,sets]}]}]],                   
          [{file,"orddict.erl"},{line,72}]},                                   
         {riak_core_capability,renegotiate_capabilities,1,[{file,"src/riak_core_capability.erl"},{line,441}]},
         {riak_core_capability,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/riak_core_capability.erl"},{line,213}]},
         {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]},       
         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},    
       {gen_server,call,                                                       
        [riak_core_capability,                                                 
         {register,                                                            
          {riak_core,vnode_routing},{capability,                                                         
           [proxy,legacy],                                                     
           legacy,                                                             
           {riak_core,legacy_vnode_routing,[{true,legacy},{false,proxy}]}}}, infinity]}}}}}}
```

How could I proceed from here ?

Answer (score 1):

The [cuttlefish config tool](https://github.com/basho/cuttlefish) uses extensible schemas. There is a reference for how to write new settings at https://github.com/basho/cuttlefish/wiki/Cuttlefish-for-Erlang-Developers

The block below will define a riak.conf setting that should look like this:

`erlang.distribution.interface = 192.168.0.42`

and a translation function to turn that into a 4-tuple and insert it into the generated app.config like this:

`{kernel,[{inet_dist_use_interface, {192,168,0,42}}]}`

You could add this block to an existing .schema file in /usr/lib/riak/lib.
Or you could create a new schema file like "0-my-custom.schema" to make it less likely to get stomped during upgrade.

```
{mapping, "erlang.distribution.interface", "kernel.inet_dist_use_interface", [
  {commented, "true"},
  {datatype, string},
  hidden
]}.

{translation, "kernel.inet_dist_use_interface",
 fun(Conf) ->
  IPStr = cuttlefish:conf_get("erlang.distribution.interface", Conf),
  list_to_tuple([ list_to_integer(Octet) || Octet <- string:tokens(IPStr,".")])
 end
}.
```

Comment: Hi Joe. Terrific answer. That does it indeed. Wonder how i could have missed the cuttlefish schemas. Thanks a lot!